# Is this Clang's bug or my bug?

Tags: c++, floating-point, clang, rounding

Run the the following C++ program twice. Once with the given destructor and once with `std::fesetround(value);` removed from the destructor. Why do I receive different outputs? Shouldn't destructor be called after function `add`? I ran both versions on http://cpp.sh/ and Clang++ 6.0, and g++ 7.2.0. For g++, I also included `#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS on` in the source code, nothing changed.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cfenv>

struct raii_feround {
  raii_feround() : value(std::fegetround()) {    }
 ~raii_feround() { std::fesetround(value); }
  inline void round_up  () const noexcept { std::fesetround(FE_UPWARD  ); }
  inline void round_down() const noexcept { std::fesetround(FE_DOWNWARD); } 
  template<typename T>
  T add(T fst, T snd) const noexcept { return fst + snd; }
private: 
  int value; };

float a = 1.1;
float b = 1.2;
float c = 0;
float d = 0;

int main() {   
    {
        raii_feround raii;
        raii.round_up();
        c = raii.add(a, b);
    }
    {
        raii_feround raii;
        raii.round_down();
        d = raii.add(a, b);
    }
    std::cout << c << "\n"; // Output is: 2.3
    std::cout << d << "\n"; // Output is: 2.3 or 2.29999
}
```

Comment: You have not checked that `fegetround` returns a non-negative number.

Comment: I'm not familiar with these functions, but are you sure they do what you think they do? [The documentation I'm looking at](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/fenv/feround) gives an example relating to `rint`, relating to rounding to the nearest integer. Since you're not invoking `rint` (or its friends), I wouldn't expect `fesetround` to have the slightest effect on the implementation-defined result of your inexact floating-point operations. That being said, they're obviously having _some_ effect so what do I know :)

Comment: [cpp.sh uses GCC 4.9.2, not Clang.](http://cpp.sh/v03/about.html) Per the C and C++ standards, you should put `#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS on` in the source to tell the compiler you are accessing the floating-point environment. However, support for non-default floating-point modes has always been spotty in many C and C++ compilers. I cannot find [specific documentation about this for GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/), but [an old bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=29186) says it was not supported.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: `fesetround` should set the rounding mode for all floating-point operations except those that explicit use a different rounding method. It is intended to set the global mode. (Not that IEEE 754 requires a global mode, but most implementations do it that way.)

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Ah yes - pretty good list [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/fenv/FE_round) it turns out. They include your note about the pragma, too.

Comment: I checked and `fegetround` returns 0.
I test the code on Clang that is installed on my computer as well.
In destructor all I am doing is to restore the feround value. If I don't do that, I will see the expected behavior. So even when `#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS on` is not used, I don't understand where the problem is.

Comment: Inserting `#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS on` into the source at cpp.sh results in a warning that it is not supported. So that answers that.

Comment: Also, I just tested it with G++ 7.2.0 and with `#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS on` included in the code. The behavior is exactly the same. Any idea is welcome.
I compiled it using "g++ ./test/tmp2.cpp" and it does not give me any warning. So I assume it supports `#pragma`

Comment: It may be necessary to use assembly. This is a nuisance, as you also have to take steps to prevent the compiler from reordering calls to assembly routines that access the floating-point environment relative to floating-point operations. Additionally, you do not want to modify the rounding mode frequently; it is a slow operation on many processors.

Answer (score 1):

Using the floating-point environment facilities requires inserting `#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS on` into the source (or ensure that they default to `on` for the implementation you are using. (Although `STDC` is a C feature, the C++ standard says that these facilities are imported into C++ by the `<cfenv>` header.)

Doing so at cpp.sh results in “warning: ignoring #pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS [-Wunknown-pragmas]”.

Therefore, accessing and modifying the floating-point environment is not supported by the compiler at cpp.sh.

Comment: I added `#pragma`, simplified the code, compiled with g++, and saw no warning. But the behavior did not changed.

Answer (score 0):

All I needed to do was to do `std::cout << std::setprecision(30);` before calling `std::cout` in the code (`iomanip` should be included as well).

Comment: If the compiler does not support floating-point environment access, modifications to the code may have effectively random effects, as the compiler happens to reorder the environment calls one way or another during optimization. Accessing the floating-point environment without compiler support is not reliable.